Proguard rules not working after add minifyEnabled true
I am trying to run my flutter app ( I am using the lates flutter version 3.22). I am getting errors on Missing classes while trying to run release mode. I navigated to the /build/app/outputs/mapping/release/missing_rules.txt. and added the recommended rules still nothing is working. Please I would appreciate as much help as I can get.
My pro guard-rules.pro:

-keep class androidx.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleObserver
## Flutter wrapper
-keep class io.flutter.app.** { *; }
-keep class io.flutter.plugin.**  { *; }
-keep class io.flutter.util.**  { *; }
-keep class io.flutter.view.**  { *; }
-keep class io.flutter.**  { *; }
-keep class io.flutter.plugins.**  { *; }
-dontwarn io.flutter.embedding.**

-dontwarn com.google.devtools.build.android.desugar.runtime.ThrowableExtension
-dontwarn com.huawei.android.os.BuildEx$VERSION
-dontwarn com.huawei.android.telephony.ServiceStateEx
-dontwarn com.huawei.hianalytics.process.HiAnalyticsConfig$Builder
-dontwarn com.huawei.hianalytics.process.HiAnalyticsConfig
-dontwarn com.huawei.hianalytics.process.HiAnalyticsInstance$Builder
-dontwarn com.huawei.hianalytics.process.HiAnalyticsInstance
-dontwarn com.huawei.hianalytics.process.HiAnalyticsManager
-dontwarn com.huawei.hianalytics.util.HiAnalyticTools
-dontwarn com.huawei.libcore.io.ExternalStorageFile
-dontwarn com.huawei.libcore.io.ExternalStorageFileInputStream
-dontwarn com.huawei.libcore.io.ExternalStorageFileOutputStream
-dontwarn com.huawei.libcore.io.ExternalStorageRandomAccessFile
-dontwarn com.meihu.beautylibrary.MHSDK$TieZhiListCallback
-dontwarn com.meihu.beautylibrary.MHSDK
-dontwarn com.meihu.beautylibrary.bean.MHCommonBean
-dontwarn com.meihu.beautylibrary.manager.MHBeautyManager
-dontwarn com.meihu.beautylibrary.utils.UrlUtils
-dontwarn org.bouncycastle.crypto.BlockCipher
-dontwarn org.bouncycastle.crypto.engines.AESEngine
-dontwarn org.bouncycastle.crypto.prng.SP800SecureRandom
-dontwarn org.bouncycastle.crypto.prng.SP800SecureRandomBuilder

My android/build.gradle:
 buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.9.20'
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

tasks.register("clean", Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}

My android/app/build.gradle:


plugins {
    id "com.android.application"
    id "kotlin-android"
    id "dev.flutter.flutter-gradle-plugin"
    id "kotlin-kapt"
}

def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode') ?: '1'
def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName') ?: '1.0'

def keystoreProperties = new Properties()
def keystorePropertiesFile = rootProject.file('key.properties')
if (keystorePropertiesFile.exists()) {
    keystoreProperties.load(new FileInputStream(keystorePropertiesFile))
}

// def flutterProjectRoot = rootProject.projectDir.parentFile.toPath()
// def plugins = new Properties()
// def pluginsFile = new File(flutterProjectRoot.toFile(), '.flutter-plugins')
// if (pluginsFile.exists()) {
//     pluginsFile.withInputStream { stream -> plugins.load(stream) }
// }

// plugins.each { name, path ->
//     def pluginDirectory = flutterProjectRoot.resolve(path).resolve('android').toFile()
//     include ":$name"
//     project(":$name").projectDir = pluginDirectory
// }

def flutterProjectRoot = rootProject.projectDir.parentFile.toPath()

def plugins = new Properties()
def pluginsFile = new File(flutterProjectRoot.toFile(), '.flutter-plugins')
if (pluginsFile.exists()) {
    pluginsFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader -> plugins.load(reader) }
}

// plugins.each { name, path ->
//     def pluginDirectory = flutterProjectRoot.resolve(path).resolve('android').toFile()
//     include ":$name"
//     project(":$name").projectDir = pluginDirectory
// }

android {
    namespace "packagename"
    compileSdkVersion 34
    ndkVersion "26.1.10909125"

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }

    lintOptions {
        disable 'InvalidPackage'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.colorlive.prod"
        minSdkVersion 24
        targetSdkVersion 34
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
        multiDexEnabled true

        ndk {
        abiFilters  'armeabi', 'armeabi-v7a', 'arm64-v8a'
        }

        manifestPlaceholders += [
        OPENINSTALL_APPKEY : "",

        UMENG_APPKEY: '',
        UMENG_MESSAGE_SECRET: '',
        UMENG_CHANNEL: '',
        HUAWEI_APP_ID: '',
        HONOR_APP_ID: '',
        XIAOMI_APP_ID: '',
        XIAOMI_APP_KEY: '',
        OPPO_APP_KEY: '',
        OPPO_APP_SECRET: '',
        VIVO_APP_ID: '您申请的VIVO通道appid',
        VIVO_APP_KEY: '您申请的VIVO通道appkey',
        MEIZU_APP_ID: '',
        MEIZU_APP_KEY: '',
     ]
    }

    signingConfigs {
        release {
            keyAlias keystoreProperties['keyAlias']
            keyPassword keystoreProperties['keyPassword']
            storeFile keystoreProperties['storeFile'] ? file(keystoreProperties['storeFile']) : null
            storePassword keystoreProperties['storePassword']
        }
    }

    buildTypes {

        debug {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }

        release {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {
   implementation 'androidx.work:work-runtime:2.8.1'
    implementation "androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.1"
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.11.0'
    kapt 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.11.0'
}

